# zsh autocomplete anaconda environments

Tags: autocomplete, zsh, anaconda

Is it possible to get zsh to autocomplete anaconda environments that show up under `source activate`? It is annoying to always have to run `conda info -e` to figure out what each environment's name is.

Comment: There is https://github.com/esc/conda-zsh-completion but I don't know if it supports `activate`.

Comment: are you using windows or mac?

Answer (score 12):

As indicated by [asmeurer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31818491/zsh-autocomplete-anaconda-environments#comment51600405_31818491) there is [conda-zsh-completion](https://github.com/esc/conda-zsh-completion).

Install it by cloning the repository to your machine

```
git clone https://github.com/esc/conda-zsh-completion
```

and add the following to your `.zshrc`

```
fpath+=/path/to/where/you/installed/conda-zsh-completion
compinit conda
```

Note that if you're using `oh-my-zsh` the first line has to go before the line where you initiate `oh-my-zsh` and the second one after the initialisation.

Now you're able to autocomplete conda like

```
conda a<TAB> env-name-parti<TAB>
```

Answer (score 5):

For zsh, cited from [conda doc](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/configuration/enable-tab-completion.html), it recommends [conda-zsh-completion](https://github.com/esc/conda-zsh-completion/blob/master/_conda). But the document from that plugin is not that helpful. I recommend you use [antigen](https://github.com/zsh-users/antigen), which is a plugin manager for oh-my-zsh. And add this one line in `.zshrc` is good to go,

```sh
antigen bundle esc/conda-zsh-completion
```

Answer (score 1):

Following the accepted answer from @asmeurer
I found that the code did not work.
but if you add a decision.
It works.

Here you can copy paste this to add the code to your machine

```
git clone https://github.com/esc/conda-zsh-completion "${HOME}/conda-zsh-completion"
wait
echo "
# make sure conda autocomplete is after this block 
# >>> conda initialize >>>
# <<< conda initialize <<<

# then add here conda autocomplete

# git clone https://github.com/esc/conda-zsh-completion \"${HOME}/conda-zsh-completion\"
fpath+=\"${HOME}/conda-zsh-completion\"
if command -v complete >/dev/null; then # zsh or bash
  compinit conda
if command -v compinit >/dev/null; then # bash
  complete -F conda
elif command -v compdef >/dev/null; then # zsh
  compdef conda
fi

" >> "${HOME}/.zshrc" >> "${HOME}/.bashrc"
```

EDIT:
Though my fix is correct, I discovered a hiccup with conda-zsh-completion
where it add a \n error
looks something like this

```
$HOME/.zshrc:###: parse error near `\n'
```

where ### is the last number of the file, which is impossible.
trying to figure out now.
I had to disable it in the mean time.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a standard Oh-My-Zsh installation.

Clone the `conda-zsh-completions` repo into `~/.oh-my-zsh/plugins`

```
cd ~/.oh-my-zsh/plugins
git clone https://github.com/esc/conda-zsh-completion
```

Add the the `conda-zsh-completions` plugin to your `.zshrc` plugins, e.g.

```
# Typical .zshrc Oh-My-Zsh content...

plugins = (
    # Other plugins
    conda-zsh-completions
)
```

Test by typing `conda activate` followed by `Tab`. You should see a list of your environments.

Answer (score -3):

You can make an alias in your `~/.zshrc` file to do this command.

open your ~/.zshrc file in a text editor

add the following line: `alias NAME='conda info -e'`

you can set whatever name for the alias you want
then save the file and restart your terminal.

You should be able to run `NAME` to list the environment name

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, it just lets you do `conda info -e` with fewer keystrokes.

Comment: He was getting annoyed because he kept having to run a long command, does an alias solve that problem?